# Bring window of another process forward

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I have a C Legacy app, this app opens and closes windows as time goes on (its a server app).

On the same machine, I'm running a C# winforms app.

Here is my goal:
My C# app sends my C app a win32 message.  The C app opens the window up.  I want the newly opened C window to bring to front, IN FRONT OF my C# app.

Here is the process currently:

- C# sends win32 message to C
- C receives, and opens new window
- C attempts to bring itself forward
- (I'm wondering at this point if C# should be telling C to 'bring yourself in front of me')

*edit* I have everything finished except for the part where I get the C window to come to front somehow.  I currently message the C app, and it opens the new window (in front of all other windows of the same .exe), but under my C# app.

I've tried using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool AllowSetForegroundWindow(ServerWindowHandle);
```

But had no luck with it.  Do I somehow need to have my C app have "ownership" of my .net app?  The C# app is getting launched via a programinvoke.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Pretty unclear.  Who is calling SetForegroundWindow?

Comment: Added edit to hopefully explain.

Comment: To understand this issue, read the remarks section of the documentation to `SetForegroundWindow`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It meet criteria 1.  My application is currently in the foreground.  I'm actively trying to bring a different process forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what operating system you were using but through some searching I found that SetForegroundWindow apparently does not always work on Windows 7. A workaround is described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121103005839/http://www.shloemi.com/2012/09/solved-setforegroundwindow-win32-api-not-always-works/). Perhaps you could take some ideas from there and apply them in either the C or C# app to get a working solution?

Comment: Hah, your link is dead so i can't see if what you provided was the solution. 

My solution was three steps (digging through the code right now)
1) AllowSetForegroundWindow, 2) SetForegroundWindow, 3) SetActiveWindow

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the C app? If so, call [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the C app window handle. Or you could make this call from the C# app if you can get a reference to the C app window handle.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the C app already calls SetForegroundWindow.  The problem is that the it doesn't bring itself in front of the C# app (noting that the C# is the forground app at the time I send the message)